# What does "-g" option mean in sort command?

Tags: sorting, unix

Could someone explain me what `g` means in this unix command?

Comment: What do you know but not sure?

Comment: Can't you just read the man page yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sort%20-rg) for these kinds of questions. Which says;

```
-r, --reverse
       reverse the result of comparisons
-g, --general-numeric-sort
       compare according to general numerical value
```